# Limit of this expression

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can you help me solve this limite? I tried to solve it with the expression $$U_n+_1\over U_n$$, but I got 0 * infinite in the end. $$U_n$$ is the expresion of the limit.

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n! + 2^n log(n)}{3n! + n^2}$$

Comment: It would be helpful to know to which value $n$ approaches.

Comment: Sorry. n approches infinite and it is positive (sorry for the bad english).

Comment: Apart for the use of MathJax, provide context to your question in order to help other members help you. For example, what have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints*

1. Consider
   $$
   \frac{2^n\log n}{n!}<\frac{2^n}{(n-1)!}
   $$
   because $\log n<n$; now prove that $\dfrac{2^n}{(n-1)!}<\dfrac{1}{n}$ for $n>a$ (determine such $a$).
2. Prove that $\dfrac{n^2}{n!}<\dfrac{1}{n}$ for $n>b$ (determine such $b$).

Comment: If I prove tha those inequalities are true for a given a and b, I can calculate the limit with the new expressions?

Comment: @BernardoLourenço Apply squeezing and deduce a couple of limits; then divide numerator and denominator of your original expression by $n!$ and lo, the limit will appear very clearly.

Comment: Ok, I just did that and the limit give me infinite. Is it correct?

Comment: @BernardoLourenço No.

Comment: I've just discovered my error. I was considering 2^n > n!, but that was wrong. Now the limit gave me 1/3. Thanks!

Comment: I also asked this question to a friend and he told me that the limit was 0. So, the limit is 0 or 1/3?

Comment: @BernardoLourenço Maybe your friend made the same interpretation error as in the other answer: $3n!\ne(3n)!$.

Comment: So, that means I'm correct?

Comment: @BernardoLourenço If the sequence is exactly as you reported, yes.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{n!+2^{n}\log{n}}{(3n)!+n^{2}} $~$\dfrac{n!(1+\frac{2^{n}\log{n}}{n!})}{(3n)!(1+o(1/n))}$~$\dfrac{n^{n}e^{3n}}{e^{n}(3n)^{3n} } + o(\frac{1}{n}) \to 0$, because of $n^{n}/n^{3n} $ goes to $0$ with $n\to \infty$

Comment: Note that $3n!\ne(3n)!$